# Algorithm Complexity Analysis for Variable Length Queue BFS

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, analysis

I have developed an algorithm that is kind of a variation of a BFS on a tree, but it includes a probabilistic factor. To check whether a node is the one I am looking for, a statistical test is performed (I won't get into too much detail about this). If the test result is positive, the node is added to another queue (called `tested`). But when a node fails the test, the nodes in the `tested` need to be tested again, so this queue is appended to the one with the nodes yet to be tested.

In Python, considering that the queue `q` starts with the root node:

```
...
tested = []
while q:
    curr = q.pop(0)
    p = statistical_test(curr)
    if p:
        tested.append(curr)
    else:
        q.extend(curr.children())
        q.extend(tested)
        tested = []
return tested
```

As the algorithm is probabilistic, more than one node might be in `tested` after the search, but that is expected. The problem I am facing is trying to estimate this algorithm's complexity because I can't simply use BFS's complexity as `q` and `tested` will have a variable length.

I don't need a closed and definitive answer for this. What I need are some insights on how to deal with this situation.

Comment: In the worst case the program never terminates.

Comment: the size of the queues is irrelevant; the question is what is the error rate of the statistical portion

Comment: how does it not terminate? unless the test can give a different result for the same input I don't see how it wouldn't terminate.

Comment: The `statistical_test` is very relevant to the time complexity calculation here, so it's not really possible to do anything without knowing that. Read up on randomized algorithms and how their time complexity is calculated. That will give you some direction.

Comment: If the test can't give a different result, there doesn't seem to be any purpose in putting successful tests back on the queue to retest.

Comment: This process needs to eventually terminate because retest can only be initiated by a failure and a failure always results in a decrease in the size of the queue.. so I don't see how it is infinite. I see your point now about the test but I still don't think it is infinite.

Comment: I tried to make the question as simple as possible. The statistical test is a chi-squared test. Each node in the tree has a probability distribution associated with its edges.  The test compares this distribution to a distribution in another tree's node. The success rate depends on these distributions, which may vary.

Answer (score 0):

The worst case scenario is the following process:

> 1. All elements *1 : n-1* pass the test and are appended to the `tested` queue.
> 2. Element *n* fails the test, is removed from `q`, and *n-1* elements from `tested` are pushed back into `q`.
> 3. Go back to step 1 with *n = n-1*

This is a classic O(n<sup>2</sup>) process.

Comment: You are assuming that queue is initialized with all elements. If the queue is initialized with only the root node (like in a classical BFS), the algorithm returns as soon as the first node passes the test.

Comment: @Munir - that's the point in worst case analysis. The "best case" is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm questioning your assumption that the queue is initialized with all elements, not your analysis. The OP has not mentioned how the queue is setup at the start of the loop and we should not assume that.

Comment: @Munir - once again, that doesn't matter. The methodology is to analyze the worst case. I claim this is when all elements are in the queue and the process I described is taking place. Then I prove the complexity. That's how this works.

Comment: In this case, the algorithm is taking a tree as an input and setting up a queue from it starting at the root. The queue is not the input, but a step in the process The worst case should be based on the tree and not on the queue. The OP hasn't made it clear how the queue is created from the tree, and hence I feel it is unfair to make the assumption. I understand the worst case is based on worst case of input, but the input here is a tree, not a queue, just like the input to a classical BFS is a graph, not a queue. The queue is part of the implementation, not the input.

Comment: @Munir - the algorithm operates on a queue (named `q`). How this queue is initialized is not part of the algorithm. There's no mention of a tree in the algorithm and no input other then said queue. If you suspect there's something else happening, it's not what is outlined and is irrelevant from the perspective of what *is* defined and what the question is about (I'm not saying that you're necessarily wrong in thinking there's something else though).

Comment: The very first line says "I have developed an algorithm that is kind of a variation of a BFS on a tree". Also, nodes are typically used for graphs/trees, not queues. This is a poorly formed question, and I don't think we should make an attempt to answer this without further info. For example, we don't even know what the probability is of the statistical test to return true, or if the test gives the same result each time. While the question is definitely theoretically engaging, it lacks a lot of necessary info.

Comment: @Munir - the preface does mention resemblance to a tree, but *it is not a part of the defined algorithm*. The question is about the complexity of the defined algorithm. That is what I've answered. The probability is again irrelevant, dealing with worst case, a 99.9% chance is no different from a 0.0001%. But it's very obvious you think otherwise, and you have every right for that. It's a shame OP asked a question and left, but that's just how SO is..

Comment: Fair enough. To each his own. :) I can only hope OP sees this and improves the question.

Comment: I am sorry that the question is not well formed. The algorithm has lots of other details, but I tried to make it as simple as possible to analyze its core. I will try to come up with some improvements to better explain it and then edit the question.

Comment: I was revising this and I think the complexity might be a little lower. It is not possible that all states from 1:n-1 are in the tested list. The worst case scenario is when the tree expands homogeneously and all the elements in the last layer are in tested except the last one and it fails. I think this reduces the complexity to O(n*log(n)).